# Cobalt browser running JQuery

Tags: cobalt

We would like to port our application running on some other browser, to run in Cobalt.
Our application uses extensively JQuery.
Running it in Cobalt is quite a challenge. Does any one have some idea about alternatives to JQuery that run in Cobalt?

**Note**: We are targeting Cobalt 20.stable

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question depends on what do you need JQuery for. JQuery used to be a browser abstraction layer but lost most of its appeal since browsers improved their support of web standards.

If you need a component model, try Angular. There are known production apps that use Angular on Cobalt (but it doesn't mean that everything will work out of the box).